# Did Two-Face's coin ever land on its edge?

Tags: dc, batman

I vaguely recall it did just that in a DC 100 page special. Can someone say if it did and point me to the example?

Comment: I've seen this happen in the flesh. Math teacher was demonstrating probability. The lesson was a little diverted a little after that.

Comment: To save everyone else some time: "*Extrapolations based on the model suggest that **the probability of an American nickel landing on edge is approximately 1 in 6000 tosses.***" Source: [Murray & Teare](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993PhRvE..48.2547M), 1993

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[image: Two-Face is vexed by an undecided coin toss]]

It happened in Detective Comics #66, Two-Face's first comic. Batman switched his coin with a loaded one that would always land on its edge and Two-Face couldn't act due to his dependence on the coin flip.

The 100 page Spectacular, which you mentioned is *The* [DC 100 Page Spectacular](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DC_100-Page_Super_Spectacular_Vol_1_20) and the story is a reprint of the one in Detective Comics #66.

Comment: I was about to answer that it happened in the 90's animated series, where Batman substituted the coin with a coin that always landed on the edge. I guess the animated series directly took it from the comic.

Comment: Thx Axelrod, this is exactly the comic I was looking for!

Comment: This is a replaced coin. Did the original ever land on it's side?

Comment: @Mast As far as I can tell, no.

Answer (score 25):

## Yes.

[image]

Above, we see Two-Face's coin landing on edge in Detective Comics 66 — *the very first comic in which Two-Face appears!*

Comment: Thx! If anyone knows of the 100pg special I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @AthenaWidget : The same exact story was reprinted in the 100 Page Special Vol 1 # 20, which is where you would have seen it --- see Axelrod's answer. :-)

Comment: @AthenaWidget : Feel free to accept Axelrod's instead, as his is more complete!

Comment: Thx Praxis. I was hesitant.

Comment: I'm amazed at the resourcefulness in this forum.

Comment: @AthenaWidget : Welcome to SFF:SE.  We're a dedicated bunch --- and we always get our answer!  ;-)

Comment: Is the use of the name "Kent" in the first panel a typesetting error, or did Two-Face really have the last name Kent instead of Dent in AC#66?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the reputation to post a comment but like Nate Kerkhofs was curious about why Batman called Two-Face 'Kent' - DC Wiki <http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Two-Face>: *Two-Face made his debut as Harvey Kent, however DC soon changed the name to "Harvey Dent", as to not confuse the character with that of Superman's alter ego.*

Answer (score 15):

I know you were asking specifically about the comics, but it also occurred in Batman: The Animated Series.

Comment: Is it ok to link this video?  Is copyright an issue?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - It's fine.  If there's a copyright issue, it's between the copyright holder, Youtube, and the person who put the video on Youtube.  None of whom are involved here.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer fair use, no different from posting screenshots which happens regularly